# REGEX_LIKE not selecting correct result

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to select numbers starting with one `+` character and having only digits afterward from a varchar column.  I have used the `regex_like` operator but it also selects special character in the result.

Expected Correct value:

```
+369
+6589445
+5896552
```

Wrong:

```
693
+4534dfgfgf#
+3435435*%
```

I tried,

```
SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Column , '^[+][0-9]');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select values starting with `+` and then 1 or more digits, use

```
^[+][0-9]+$
         ^^
```

The `$` will force the end-of-string boundary and `+` will allow matching 1 or more occurrences of the construct the plus quantifies (the `[0-9]` character class).

Here is a [demo showing how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/xL2jZ1/1).